# How many tables can I join together with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

How many tables can I join together with MySQL? So far I have only been joining 3 tables. What's the max for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Limits in MySQL > [Limits of Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/joins-limits.html):

> The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61. This also applies to the number of tables that can be referenced in the definition of a view.

Comment: How did you miss it when you googled? I got to it in two clicks when I searched for "mysql limits".

Comment: didn't show up on google when I searched `How many tables can I join together with MySQL?`

Comment: @Barmar: Can we increase the number of joins allowed?

Comment: @KrutiPatel If there were a customization option I'd expect that to be mentioned in the documentation I linked to. But MySQL is open-source, so maybe you can change the limit and recompile.

Comment: @Barmar: But I don't know how to change the limit. Can you please help me with the solution?

Comment: Instead of increasing the limit, I suggest you break it up into smaller queries, and save the results in temporary tables. Then join those temp tables.

Comment: I can't help you with modifying the MySQL code. It would probably be a full day of research and coding, it's not a trivial question.

Comment: But you could try downloading the source code and see if you can find an array whose size is 61. Maybe it's just a `#define` somewhere, which you can edit and recompile.