# how many max join table at mysql? and how to count it?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Maybe this question is related with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966790/how-many-tables-can-i-join-together-with-mysql).
I have Question..
My friend said that mysql has limitation on max join table.
And I get this :

> The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join
>   is 61. This also applies to the number of tables that can be
>   referenced in the definition of a view.

Is that true?
Then, for example:
I have select query and join 2 table:
left join a on b.id = a.b_id
So, how to count the number of joined table?
Per table? or Per join?
so, that query marked as 1 (per join) or 2(per table)? 61 (max limit) is per table or per join?

Comment: I think the quote is very specific: "maximum number of ***tables***"; so you count the tables. If you use views in your queries, you must also count the joined tables in your join... But, honestly... will you ever join 61 tables in a single query?

Comment: I've written huge queries of hundreds of lines, but they use maybe 25 different tables. That was in Oracle by the way, and quite exceptional, since such queries are often hard to maintain and especially hard to test and debug. MySQL starts giving up at around a dozen table, performencewise. I wouldn't know why anyone would use 61 (or 62 if you think the limit is about joins) tables in one query in MySQL, and I certainly wouldn't want to be the one optimizing it. :)

Comment: You know it would have been pretty easy to test? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/043dd/8 Add one more join and MySQL goes boom.

Answer (score 4):

The text is clear on that: "The maximum number of tables [...] is 61". Followed by "This also applies to the number of tables [in] a view".

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL has a limit of 61 tables in a join.

It's fairly easy to hit the 61 tables limit if you use generated sql and lots of nested views.

### So after a bit of testing I found this out

- If the table is outside the join it will not count views do not count
  as tables unless they don't select from any table, for example:
  `CREATE VIEW v_now AS SELECT NOW() AS now`
- Joining the same table twice will count as two tables
- Tables in the where clause `WHERE EXISTS` do not count

Let's say we have this setup

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE VIEW v_now AS SELECT NOW() AS now;
CREATE VIEW v_test AS SELECT t.id FROM test t LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id!=t.id AND t2.id > t.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

and this select

```
SELECT t.id, (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE id=1) AS one FROM test t 
JOIN v_test vt ON t.id = vt.id 
JOIN v_test vt2 ON t.id = vt2.id 
JOIN test t3 ON t3.id = t.id
JOIN v_now now
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test)
```

then it will count like this this

```
SELECT t.id, (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE id=1) AS one 
FROM test t (+1)
JOIN v_test vt ON t.id = vt.id (+2)
JOIN v_test vt2 ON t.id = vt2.id (+2)
JOIN test t3 ON t3.id = t.id (+1)
JOIN v_now now (+1)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test) (+0)

test (+1)
v_test (+0)
    test (+1)
    test (+1)
v_test (+0)
    test (+1)
    test (+1)
test (+1)
v_now (+1)
```

so that would count as 7 tables

[As mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10587413/php-guru)

```
SELECT id FROM tbl t
JOIN (SELECT NOW() AS now)
```

This would count as 2 tables.

Disclaimer: I did not test the above code, the example I tested with was far too complicated and was hitting the 61 join table limit.

Comment: Would (SELECT NOW() AS now) be counted as a table? Even though there is no actual table referenced.

Comment: @PHPGuru that's an excellent question but sadly I don't know, I'll make a note to check it and update back here (May take a while), if you find the answer before then please add a comment here and I will update the answer.

Comment: I did find the answer actually and yes it counts as a table if used in a join.